# Como puedo moverme de una pagina a otra haciendo click sobre un icono en un div?

Tags: java, html

Hola estoy intentando escribir un codigo que al hacer click a un icono que tengo en un div y que dependiendo del tipo de usuario dentro de session.getAttribute() decida a que pagina ir. El problema es que no se como escribir este codigo de manera que el codigo identifique que se esta haciendo el click. Supongo que debo hacer uso de scriptless. Agradecere mucho su ayuda.

Este es el icono que tengo:

```
<div id="wb_IconFont2" style="position:absolute;left:1225px;top:162px;width:115px;height:133px;text-align:center;z-index:27;">
            <a href="muroUsuario.jsp" title="tu perfil"><div id="IconFont2"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div></a></div>
```

El codigo que estoy intentando:

```
<%/*
       if(session.getAttribute("sUsuario").equals("admin){
             request.getRequestDispatcher("muroAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
         }else{
             request.getRequestDispatcher("muroUsuario.jsp").forward(request, response);
         }
```

*/
%>

Comment: Si te das cuenta te falta cerrar una doble comilla en el `.equals(...)` dentro del `if` `if(session.getAttribute("sUsuario").equals("admin"){`

Comment: gracias @DavidFernándezFlores por la observación. Pero aun no logro lo que deseo. Como puedo hacer para que el icono al darle click, me haga el dispatch a una de esas paginas? No se como llamar ese icono a mi codigo.

Comment: Es más fácil de entender y trabajar, si en lugar de hacer todo con Scriptlet, usa el scriptlet solo para crear una variable en JavaScript, y usa javascript para controlar lo que hace el DIV. Tenga un javascript como var = '<%session.getAttribute("sUsuario")'%>, y cree un javascript function para controlar lo que quiera hacer con el div.